# ng-bootstrap typeahead determine selection

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap

I've got a typeahead element in my Angular 5 application.  What I can't figure out is how to determine the selection.  I have this for my `resultTemplate`:

```js
<ng-template #listSelectionFormatter let-r="result">
    <span (click)="onWorkerSelected(r)">{{r.wwid}} - {{r.fullName}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

So if I click on one of the selected items my callback happens and I can store the result.  But if they hit the tab key instead, I don't know how to grab the selection.

I basically need to be able to call `propagateChange` as this is used in a `ControlValueAccessor`.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api#NgbTypeahead: an output selectItem emits every time an item is selected. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnku9p?file=app/typeahead-basic.html. Remove that (click) event handler.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!